# SQL create table with integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I want to have in a database a table with single column with integers (1,2,...) since it can be helpful for certain joins.

I came up with a solution using a loop. Is there a more efficient way of creating such a table?

**My solution**

```
CREATE TABLE #NUM
(
  NUM int
)

DECLARE @i int=1
WHILE @i<10000
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #Temp
  SELECT @i 
  SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: No, not really. (Does it matter, you create this table once and keep it forever.)

Comment: This may be more appropriate for the code review site since you don't have any issues: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
row_number() over (order by message_id) num
into #Table
from sys.messages
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do this using a tally table

```
    ;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e2 CROSS JOIN e2 AS b) -- 100*100
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e3 ORDER BY n;
```

check [*here*](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2) for more info

Answer (score 0):

This is the same principle as the answer by NoDisplayName, but I think it is a little cleaner (my opinion):

```
;WITH TBL(ROW_NUM) AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ROW_NUM
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ROW_NUM+1
    FROM TBL
    WHERE ROW_NUM < 100
)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T1.ROW_NUM) AS ROW_NUM
FROM TBL T1
JOIN TBL T2 ON 1=1
JOIN TBL T3 ON 1=1
```